# How to "reset" id in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I've made a database with users and each user has an id that is autoincremented. But when I delete a user from the table, the id doesn't "reset":

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: ..that's by design, unless you also TRUNCATE the table, which would be unusual

Answer (score 22):

You need to run a UPDATE Query.

```
SET @reset = 0; UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET id = @reset:= @reset + 1;
```

Comment: This is should be marked as answer. Pure DML solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can reset the auto increment counter to the next available value with:

```
alter table MYTABLE auto_increment = 0;
```

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't fix this.  The database is doing *exactly* what it is designed to do.  As the first line in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) on `AUTO_INCREMENT` says:

> The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity
>   for new rows . . .

Note:  Nothing about sequentiality or not having gaps.

The auto-incremented value is designed to uniquely identify each row (among other things).  Once a row is identified, that doesn't change.  This identifier could be used by other tables (foreign key references).  This identifier could be written down by someone to remember that id=378 had something special.

The key idea is that the value does not change over time.

There is no problem having gaps in such identifiers.  If you want to

Comment: Upvoted. This is useful info. Looks like it cuts off at the end of the last sentence, though.